# Problem with latest Chrome and Flexbox/overflow

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, flexbox, overflow

We have a div element with lots of sub elements and this is not displaying correctly in latest Chrome (79) on Mac. We are getting two scrollbars and it looks like the list is taking up too much space and forcing the titlePanel and actionPanel out of the viewport. See screenshots.
We want the UI to take up the full height of the browser window, and we want the list element to take up remaining space and have a scrollbar inside it.

Correct:

[image]

Not correct (notice the two blue panels and the two scroll bars):

[image]

This used to work fine up till Chrome 78 and is still working fine in latest Safari on Mac. We have also tested on Chrome/Safari on latest iOS and here it also works. It does NOT work on latest Chrome on Mac and on Samsung S10, so we expect that the latest update of Chrome has introduced some changes.

However, I'm not completely sure that our HTML/CSS is correct. We are able to fix the issue by adding overflow-y:auto to the contentPanel, but I expected the overflow on the list element to be sufficient (which was the case until latest Chrome update).

Is our HTML/CSS bad or is there an issue with latest Chrome?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.mainPanel {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: stretch;
  background: blue;
}

.contentPanel {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: stretch;
  height: 100%;

   /*overflow-y:auto*/;
}

.titlePanel {
  flex: 0 0 auto; 
}
.actionPanel {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.list {
  height:100%;
  overflow-y:auto;
  background:tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="mainPanel">
    <div class="contentPanel">
      <div class="titlePanel">TITLE</div>
      <div class="list">
        <div>entry</div>
        <div>entry</div>
        <div>entry</div>
        <div>entry</div>
        <div>entry</div>
        <div>entry</div>
        <div>entry</div>
        <div>entry</div>
        <div>entry</div>
        <div>entry</div>
        <div>entry</div>
        <div>entry</div>
        <div>entry</div>
        <div>entry</div>
        <div>entry</div>
        <div>entry</div>
        <div>entry</div>
        <div>entry</div>
        <div>entry</div>
        <div>entry</div>
        <div>entry</div>
        <div>entry</div>
        <div>entry</div>
        <div>entry</div>
        <div>entry</div>
        <div>entry</div>
        <div>entry</div>
        <div>entry</div>
        <div>entry</div>
        <div>entry</div>
        <div>entry</div>
        <div>entry</div>
        <div>entry</div>
        <div>entry</div>
        <div>entry</div>
        <div>entry</div>
        <div>entry</div>
        <div>entry</div>
        <div>entry</div>
        <div>entry</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="actionPanel">Actions</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue with your html/css is that your `contentPanel` has 100% `height` and you have another sibling element (`actionPanel`) underneath. The total height is over 100%, so you get that outer scrollbar.

A quick-fix is to put `actionPanel` inside `contentPanel`.

Or make the `contentPanel` take less height.
e.g. `height: calc(100% - 18px);`

Comment: Hmmm, yes good point. I need to check if my test case matches my business case. Putting actionPanel inside the contentPanel solves my problem - I just need to verify that I did not write a wrong test case.

Comment: But I still think that the latest Chrome update, brought some changes that changed how my UI look - as it used to work as intended. I just worry that if I fix my UI now, it will break if Chrome decides to fix/rollback/change whatever they updated in version 79.

Answer (score 4):

Just wanted to chime in with another possible solution. I have struggled with this issue for several hours (that's how I got here), and indeed it only happens on Mac after having updated Chrome yesterday.

What I ended up doing was to replace `height: 100%` on `.list` with:

```
flex: 1 1 auto;
height: 0;
```

This seems to do the trick for Chrome 79 and it still works as intended on Chrome on Windows and Safari. I haven't tested it in other browsers, so you might want to do that.

Comment: We ended up with the same solution: flex: 1 1 0. Using auto it looks to the height attribute which also was 0 in your example.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to remove all height properties from your code and it worked well as you mentioned in the first image displayed. Maybe setting only one container div to `height: 100%;` will assure your desired result

Comment: Thanks for you comment. If I remove all height properties and/or only leave 100% on the outer container, I get a scrollbar that scrolls the entire UI. I want the blue bars in the top and bottom always to be visible - and only have scrollbar in the red area. Hope that makes sense...