# Page gets cut off after chrome 79 updates

Tags: html, css, reactjs, google-chrome

It seems like lots of my previous working pages are getting cutoff after chrome updates to 79. Another one what are the issues?

Comment: Hey Youchen. What do you mean by cut off? Is it a overflow issue? Could you somehow provide a URL or code so that its possible to see what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the same problem I was having. In my case it was due to a scrollable container inside of a flexbox element. The scrollable container had a height of 100% and was previously scrolling as the content inside grew. After the Chrome 79 update the container would push down below the window.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59372273/4967315) to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59355171/problem-with-latest-chrome-and-flexbox-overflow) question resolved it for me.

Just switching the scrollable container styles from `height: 100%` to:

```
flex: 1 1 auto;
height: 0;
```